# Can i update the database without paypal redirecting to success page?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

Sorry i'm a newbie at this PAYPAL IPN

so i got my IPN file. 
so my question is, once the user has paid gets redirected to the success/ipn page my script updates the records. 
 but what if the user didnt get redirected, i tested it myself paypal redirects me to the PAYPAL THANK YOU ORDER page and then mozilla pops up a window alert saying that "your connecting to an insecure site bla bla CLICK (yes) or (cancel)" if i click yes then i get redirected to my success/ipn page, 
but if i click cancel i will stay on the PAYPAL THANK YOU PAGE 
so im worried that the user might click cancel and he wont get redirected and the data wont be updated

so how do i update the database without paypal redirecting me to my success/ipn page

Please advise, and dont vote down please,

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // change to [...]sandbox.paypal[...] when using sandbox to test
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));


// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// WRITE LOG 
$fh = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fh, $res .'--'. $req);
fclose($fh);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL){
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
}else{
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
 }
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];

// Insert your actions here
if(($payment_status == 'Completed') && ($receiver_email == 'paypal-test@bolddata-ap.com')){
        include('php/config.php'); //Open Database connection

        $check = $dbo->prepare('SELECT * FROM order_bytes WHERE trans_id = ?');
        $check->execute(array($txn_id));

        if($check->rowCount() >= 1){
            die('ERROR FOUND SAME TXN ID IN DATABASE');
        }else{

            /*Data token = EAZZn0OkC2zo4H3CF9vrrSlU-grBGr0oQzE8NZ6jnYGRTuJkJS0howDNK48*/
                        $stmt = $dbo->prepare("UPDATE `order_bytes` SET stat=? ,paid=?, trans_id=? WHERE `tracker`=? AND `user_id`=?");
                        /*$stmt->bindValue(":stats", 'PAID', PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(":pay", $item_price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(":it", $item_transaction, PDO::PARAM_STR);                            
                        $stmt->bindParam(":trackers", $_SESSION['random_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(":uid", $_SESSION['byte_user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);*/
                        if(!$stmt->execute(array($payment_status,$payment_amount,$txn_id,$_SESSION['tracker'],$_SESSION['byte_user']))){
                            //print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
                        }else {
                            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                                notify(getbyteuser($item_no),'A User Ordered your Byte<br />Tracker ID: '.$_SESSION['tracker'].'','NEW ORDER');
                            //mail_booked($item_transaction);

                            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\"><h3>Thank you<br>Your payment has been successfull</h3>
                                    <p>Keep track of your order in your Dashboard</p>
                                </div>";
                            echo '<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary" rel="noindex" nofollow="">Done</a>';

                            }else{
                                print alert_danger('Error');
                            }

                        }

        }
}
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
     echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm away from my computer currently for the next hour. Keep regularly checking this topic.  When I return home I'll get tinkering and figure something out or make some rough recommendations

Comment: <strike>Don't</strike> Never use GetMagicQuotes, that function is broken, see: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: @Johan noted. And about my question???  Any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused about IPN and return page.

This is wrong:

> so my question is, once the user has paid gets redirected to the success/ipn page

IPN is not a success page. It is a page that PayPal calls in the background to notify you about a transaction status. It is independent of the user session. (notify_url)

The page that PayPal redirects the user after complete (or cancel) a payment is different from the IPN. This is related to the user session (return_url)

Comment: Ok not a success page. Noted, so if IPN is not a success page then how do I update the database once the user has paid?? Is there suppose to be another thing I should do??

Comment: You can update your database with the code you presented. That will be called by PayPal but your user won't see it. So i would remove any output from it (like "Keep track of your order in your Dashboard").

Normally IPN comes before the user is redirected. So, in the thank you page you can simple check the database and see the status. Or just print something like "your order is in process".

Comment: Yes I did that, Originally my success page wasn't the IPN page, i change it bcoz it was not updating the database every time the user has paid. That's why I change my Success page to my IPN page then it can only update. But then I realize it makes no difference from using PDT coz PDT can only give you the data once it redirects to the success page, so that's when I knew I was doing it wrong. So I'm trying to say here is that I already tried using what you mention above b4 I even posted this question.

Comment: ...has your question been answered?

Comment: No, it has not been answered yet

Comment: I mean, what is the question exactly if you now you know that IPN is not the success page?

Comment: b4 posting this question. I didn't use IPN as my success page I use a static one. So what I mean is I already did that b4 posting. So it's not an answer bcoz I've already done it. And it didn't work that's why I use my IPN page as my success page. And that didn't go the way as I wanted as well, That's why I posted this question  so even if I were to revert back my return URL to my static page. It still doesn't update the database.